# Libgdx Fitting screen

Tags: libgdx

My game has 2 black bars on the side on mobile. I have tried to make it fit with FitViewport and it should fit the screen as the game is a platformer and scrolls sideways so should always fit the screen in terms of width so i dont know why there is 2 black bars. I just wanted some help on how to fix this problem and to get it filling the full screen on all general screen sizes. Thanks alex.

```
public static final float V_WIDTH = 2234;
public static final float V_HEIGHT = 1400;
```

[image]

```
public PlayScreen(MarioBros game) {
    this.game = game;

    gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new FitViewport(MarioBros.V_WIDTH / MarioBros.PPM , MarioBros.V_HEIGHT / MarioBros.PPM , gameCam);
```

Comment: The FitViewport can have black bars. So if you won't no black bars, you will have to use a different viewport. Is that what you want? No black bars?

Comment: ExtendViewport is the right choice in like 90% of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex, go with StretchViewport:

```
public PlayScreen(MarioBros game) {
    this.game = game;

    gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new StretchViewport(MarioBros.V_WIDTH / MarioBros.PPM , MarioBros.V_HEIGHT / MarioBros.PPM , gameCam);
```